# Backbone.js routes are not being routed

Tags: routes, backbone.js

I have following piece of code  from my Backbone project:

```
App.Controllers.Test = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    'test': 'test',
    'help': 'help'
  },

  help: function() {
    console.log('help');
  },

  test: function() {
    console.log('test');
  },

  initialize: function() {
    console.log('init');
  }
});


// ...

new App.Controllers.Test()
```

But all I ever see in my console is `init` even if call the url with `#test` or `#help`
Does anybody know what is missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your initialize function will always run first, so your router is being instantiated, but perhaps you haven't invoked History, after you invoke your router you need a line of code like:

```
Backbone.history.start({pushState: true})
```

The pushState option is if you are using newer browsers that have the history api, since you're calling your routes with a hash, you might not need pushState.

If your router is assigned to the variable routes, your code may look like this:

```
var routes = new Backbone.Router.extend({...});

Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
```

Comment: Gosh, that was it! Thanks for clarifying that I need to use `Backbone.history` for that :)

Comment: Glad I could help! Another gotcha is to make sure your server can respond to the routes you specify, even if it just means every server route initially loads the same index.html, otherwise you can get a lot of 404 errors.